# Behavioral change in method perspectiveActivated() of interface IPerspectiveListener from Eclipse RCP 3.0 to 4.4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In my application I have implemented the interface `IPerspectiveListener` with the method `perspectiveActivated()`. In Eclipse RCP 3.0, this method was called on startup and when the user changes the perspective. In Eclipse 4.4 the method is only called when the user changes the perspective. This leads to the problem that a user is able to use menu entries which should be disabled based on the perspective which is opened. This faulty behavior only exists after startup. When I change a perspective, `perspectiveActivated()` is called and everything is grayed out like it should be.

I there a possibility for me to look up changes in behavior from one version of Eclipse to another for methods like this? (like patch-notes in gaming?)

No changes to the program code were made, it can only be a change of the underlying framework.

Comment: There is a possible workaround listed [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/85158/). Eclipse internals were more of less completely rewritten for Eclipse 4.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384799 comment 4 suggests that this is a bug. but there is no bug opened to this specific problem. is this fixed in version 4.5?

Comment: I tested this example http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/03/31/replacing-the-perspective-switcher-in-rcp-apps/ in Eclipse RCP 4.5 and added the methods `perspectiveActivated()` and `perspectiveChanged()`. They both don't get called on startup. I open a bug report when I have time and use the result to answer this question.